# Is it wrong to thow or catch the Exception Class (every Exception possible)?

Tags: exception

I know that a question like this probably depends on what the programmer intends his program to do however at school we were taught to **never** throw or catch `Exception` (the class) and rather make sure it throws one of the subclasses more specific to the kind of Runtime error we expect can happen (eg IllegalArgumentException). However, I'm working now and in the 'real world' I see a lot of scenarios in code I work on where the previous programmers threw `Exception` for everything in a method or catch `Exception` like that rather than one of its more specific subclasses.

So I'm wondering, Is it ok to throw and catch everything like this, is it bad programming to do so?

Comment: Short answer: never catch Exception.  Long answer: never catch Exception, throwing is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My idea is, the way of handle the exceptions should also depend on the type of the application you are creating. For example if you are developing some kind of a framework or a library you should not try to print error messages or log them, you have throw them because it will be responsibility of the other developers who are using your framework/library to handle the exceptions gracefully when they are using your code.

If you are developing some kind of a front end application then you should be more delicate with exception handling. I think it's better you use you own exception classes when possible, because that will help you to pin point the bugs or runtime issues in your application later. When you handle exceptions you should always go from more specific exceptions to general exceptions. And finally you should handle the exceptions of the "Exception" super class so it will make sure that your application doesn't crash, preferably you should have a try-catch block in the main entry point of your application. What ever happens in handling exceptions logging the errors is a good practice when it comes diagnosing the errors later.

Answer (score 1):

It is not wrong to do that but it can make your debugging life very difficult. Many people will catch the exception class and log the Exception.Message. There is not enough detail and, especially if you're working on large systems where you can't always step through the live code etc, it will be a tedious task.

I tend to catch specific exceptions and handle them accordingly BUT I also catch the Exception class to make sure all exceptions are caught going forward (An object might be changed to include more exceptions in future framework versions).

Answer (score 0):

It is bad practice, just as you have learnt.

One major exception to the rule is a top-level exception handler (to catch unhandled exceptions) - the purpose of this would be to log exception so they can be read by a developer later and used to fix the application (and would normally rethrow in order to crash the application - rather than leaving it in an inconsistent state).